# The IF statement is not working when working with a file and an external variable

Tags: if-statement, awk

I have 2 files,

file1:

```
YARRA2
```

file2:

```
59204.9493055556    
59205.5930555556
```

So, file1 has 1 line and file2 has 2 lines. If file1 has 1 line, and file2 has more than 1 line, I want to repeat the lines in file1 according to the number of lines in file2.
So, my code is this:

```
eprows=$(wc -l < file2)

awk '{ if( NR<2 && eprows>1 ) {print} {print}}' file1
```

but the output is

```
YARRA2
```

Any idea? I have also tried with

```
awk '{ if( NR<2 && $eprows>1 ) {print} {print}}' file1
```

but it is the same

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Ed: Sorry I am going to reopen this because this is not just about passing shell variable to awk. Even if we add `-v eprows=5` OP's attempt will print only 2 lines instead of `4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```bash
awk '
NR == FNR {
   ++n2
   next
}
{
   s = $0
   print;
   ++n1
}
END {
   if (n1 == 1)
      for (n1=2; n1 <= n2; ++n1)
         print s
}' file2 file1

YARRA2
YARRA2
```

Answer (score 1):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { cnt++; next }                    # count number of records in 1st file

                                           # no specific processing for 2nd file => just scan through to end of file

END     { if (FNR==1 && cnt >=2)           # if 2nd file has just 1 record (ie, FNR==1) and 1st file had 2+ records then ...
             for (i=1;i<=cnt;i++)          # for each record in 1st file ...
                 print                     # print current (and only) record from 2nd file
        }
' file2 file1
```

This generates:

```
YARRA2
YARRA2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eprows=$(wc -l < file2)

awk '{ if( NR<2 && eprows>1 ) {print} {print}}' file1
```

Oops!  You stepped hip-deep in mixed languages.

The `eprows` variable is a shell variable. It's not accessible to other processes except through the environment, unless explicitly passed somehow.  The awk program is inside single-quotes, which would prevent interpreting `eprows` even if used correctly.

The value of a shell variable is obtained with `$`, so

```
echo $eprows
2
```

One way to insert the value into your awk script is by interpolation:

```
awk '{ if( NR<2 && '"$eprows"'>1 ) {print} {print}}' file1
```

That uses a lesser known trick: you can switch between single- and double-quotes as long as you don't introduce spaces.  Because double-quoted strings in the shell are interpolated, awk sees

```
{ if( NR<2 && 2>1 ) {print} {print} }
```

Awk also lets you pass values to *awk* variables on the command line, thus:

```
awk -v eprows=$eprows '{ if( NR<2 && eprows >1 ) {print} {print}}' file1
```

but you'd have nicer awk this way:

```
awk -v eprows=$eprows 'NR < 2 && eprows > 1 { {print} {print} }' file1
```

whitespace and brevity being elixirs of clarity.

That works because in the awk *pattern* / *action* paradigm, *pattern* is anything that can be reduced to true/false. It need not be a regex, although it usually is.

Comment: That's a lot of prescription, Ed.  I gave the OP some options and ways to think about the problem.  I never quote shell variables unless I know they may include whitespace, because if there is unexpected whitespace, the quotes convert a syntax error to a semantic error.  Here, `$eprows` must be an integer.  If it's 2 strings, unquoted, **awk** will complain that it can't open the 2nd string as a file (or something), but, quoted, will run and always compare false.

Comment: You ignored my rationale.  Are you really so sure of yourself that someone else's reasoned approach is invalid simply because you have his practice on your *never* list?

Comment: For anyone interested in the pros/cons of using unquoted variables, see [security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) (which provides references that address more than just the security issues)